# Adding random values from array with some probability

Tags: c#, arrays, probability

Let's say I have a code for a windows form, that generates greetings when you press a button.

```
   string[] Greetings = new string[] { "Hi", "Hello", "Howdy!", "Hey" };
   string[] Smilies = new string[] {";)", ":)", "=)", ":-)" };

   Random rand = new Random();
   string Greet = Greetings[rand.Next(0, Greetings.Length)];
   string Smile = Smilies[rand.Next(0, Smilies.Length)];
   TextBox.Text = Greet + " " + Smile;
   Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
```

What if I want to add smilies with a probability of X%. So that they do not appear all the time, but with a chance I set in the code? What is a good way to do it?

I thought of something like this --

```
    public void chance (string source, int probability)
    {
        Random chanceStorage = new Random();
        if (probability >= chanceStorage.Next(0, 100))
            TextBox.Text = source;
    }
```

And then

```
    TextBox.Text = Greet;
    chance("_" + Smile, X);
```

Is that optimal?

Comment: `const int percentageValue = 25; double percentage = (double)percentageValue / 100; if (rand.NextDouble() <= percentage) { \\ do stuff }`

Comment: Add as much String.Empty values to your Smilies array until you reach the probability of no smilie you like.

Comment: @Corak has a good answer (if it were an answer).

Comment: Why not just divide your Smilies length by your probability and generate a random number using that quotient?  If the number generated is within the bounds of Smilies' length use the smiley, otherwise you don't use a smiley.  So if your probablity is 25%, 4 / 0.25 = 16, you'll generate a random number from 0 - 15 giving you a 25% chance of using a smiley.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - completely untested, so I'm not "sure enough" to put it as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a probability by a given percentage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342004/how-to-create-a-probability-by-a-given-percentage)

Comment: @P.K. not quite, since the answers seems to address a misconception about probability instead of actually generating a random result with a given probability.

Answer (score 2):

50% chance to smile:

```
   string[] Greetings = new string[] { "Hi", "Hello", "Howdy!", "Hey" };
   string[] Smilies = new string[] {";)", ":)", "=)", ":-)" };

   Random rand = new Random();
   string Greet = Greetings[rand.Next(0, Greetings.Length)];
   string Smile = rand.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? " "+Smilies[rand.Next(0, Smilies.Length)] : string.Empty;
   TextBox.Text = Greet + Smile;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only thing I'd change:  0.5 > rand.NextDouble(). This way probability will look more natural in code

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply generate a random double between 0, 1 (inclusive of 0 only) with [`random.NextDouble()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Then you can just check that a probability (as a value between 0 and 1) is less than the generated number.

For example

```
double chance = 0.35; //35%
bool createSmiley = rand.NextDouble() < chance;
```

This is not necessarily *exactly* precise (because of the finite precision of floating point numbers) but will get you very close.  And allows for more precision than just using `ints` as your random numbers.

A [demo of the random generation of smileys](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8gaxp).

On another note, I'd refactor your code a bit to better isolate the logic.  I'd personally just try to manipulate a single string, and set the `.Text` property once after all the string processing is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the length of your Smilies array by your probability to give a range of random numbers to generate.

4 smilies / 25% probablity = 16. So your random generator would generate a random number from 0 - 15 giving a 25% chance of using a smiley.  If the generated number is outsides the bounds of the array, don't use a smiley.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        double percentage = rand.NextDouble();

        string[] greetings = new[] { "Hi", "Hello", "Howdy!", "Hey" };
        string[] smilies = new[] { ";)", ":)", "=)", ":-)" };

        // Get a greeting
        string greet = greetings[rand.Next(0, greetings.Length)];

        // Generate the smiley index using the probablity percentage
        int randomIndex = rand.Next(0, (int)(smilies.Length / percentage));

        // Get a smiley if the generated index is within the bound of the smilies array
        string smile = randomIndex < smilies.Length ? smilies[randomIndex] : String.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", greet, smile);
    }
}
```

See working example here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/lmN5aP